# matching and update a column of a dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes `df_a` with two columns `colA`, `colB`, and `df_b` with one column `colA`.

```
df_a <- data.frame(colA = sample(1:10, 10), colB = sample(LETTERS[1:20],10))

> df_a
   colA colB
1     2    F
2     8    J
3     5    G
4     9    A
5    10    R
6     4    N
7     7    D
8     1    B
9     3    Q
10    6    H

df_b <- data.frame(colA = sample(1:10, 10))
> df_b
   colA
1     9
2     5
3     3
4     7
5     1
6     8
7     2
8     4
9    10
10    6
```

I have to create a new column `colB` in `df_b` after comparing `colA` of `df_a` with `colA` of `df_b`.

```
> df_b$colB <- df_a[df_a$colA %in% df_b$colA,'colB']

> df_b
   colA colB
1     9    F
2     5    J
3     3    G
4     7    A
5     1    R
6     8    N
7     2    D
8     4    B
9    10    Q
10    6    H
```

The corresponding values in both dataframes are not the same. For example in `df_a`, `colA` value 9 has A in `colB`. Whereas in `df_b`, `colA` value 9 has F in `colB`. Is this issue due to unsorted dataframes ?

*Note:* I couldn't find a similar question and this even might be a possible duplicate. I would like to understand the root cause of the error.

Original task was to populate values for replacing `NA` in `df_b`.

```
df_a <- data.frame(colA = sample(1:10, 10), colB = sample(LETTERS[1:10],10))
df_b <- data.frame(colA = sample(1:10, 10), colB = sample(c(LETTERS[1:10], 'NA'),10))
```

Comment: I think you want to `?merge` your data sets

Comment: Or `match` as in `df_a[match(df_b$colA, df_a$colA),'colB']`

Comment: @DavidArenburg The output is based on the order of the column in `df_a` and I would require in the order of `df_b`

Comment: So just switch the matching order, something like `df_b[match(df_a$colA, df_b$colA),'colB']`

Comment: @docendodiscimus did you mean `merge(df_b, df_a, by.x = TRUE)` ? It works fine and the output is in the sorted order of `colA`. Is there any approach to get in the actual order of  `colA` in `df_b` ??

Comment: @Prradep, read `?merge` or the linked question more carefully. `by.x = TRUE` is wrong.

Comment: @docendodiscimus, DavidArenburg Thank you, I got the idea and will use it for my requirement.