# How to retrieve multiple matching elements?

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have to two data frames `df_a`, `df_b`.

```
set.seed(143)
df_a <- data.frame(colA = sample(1:10, 10, replace=T), colB = sample(LETTERS[1:20],10))
df_a
#   colA colB
#1    10    I
#2     1    D
#3     8    R
#4     5    F
#5     1    N
#6    10    P
#7     7    E
#8     6    S
#9     6    T
#10    4    C

df_b <- data.frame(colA = sample(1:10, 10, replace=T))
df_b
#   colA
#1     9
#2     3
#3     9
#4     9
#5     3
#6    10
#7    10
#8     7
#9     4
#10    7
```

I have to update the `colB` with values from `colB` in data frame `df_a` based on the matching of the `colA` in both data frames.

```
df_a[match(df_b$colA, df_a$colA),'colB']
# [1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> I    I    E    C    E   
#Levels: C D E F I N P R S T
```

The output doesn't give more than one matched element(not a surprise!). For eg., `10` has two values `I`,`P` but only gives `I`.

```
Expected Output(something like this, maybe?):

df_a[match(df_b$colA, df_a$colA),'colB']
# [1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> I,P    I,P   E    C    E   
#Levels: C D E F I N P R S T
```

As the [`match()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576347/matching-and-update-a-column-of-a-dataframe-based-on-another-dataframe#comment60751749_36576347) function returns only the first matched value, is there any other alternative like `which()` or `%in%` for achieving the task ?

Comment: I would use `merge(df_b, df_a, by = "colA", all.x = TRUE)`, but what to do with `colA == 10`?

Comment: @m-dz need to retrieve all possible matches

Comment: So, is the code from my comment doing what you expect?

Comment: @m-dz yes and no. I was looking for solution which can be embedded as a single value with a delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `aggregate` to `paste` same matches together, and then merge, i.e.

```
merge(df_b, aggregate(colB ~ colA, df_a, paste, collapse = ','), by = 'colA', all.x = TRUE)
#   colA colB
#1     3 <NA>
#2     3 <NA>
#3     4    C
#4     7    E
#5     7    E
#6     9 <NA>
#7     9 <NA>
#8     9 <NA>
#9    10  I,P
#10   10  I,P
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have `df_b` in the original order I would use `data.table` as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_b)
setDT(df_a)

df_a[, sapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ","), by = "colA"][df_b, , on = "colA"]
```

First, `df_a[, sapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ",") , by = "colA"]` is doing exactly same aggregation on `df_a` as @Sotos proposed, and then `[df_b, , on = "colA"]` is merging the result of it with `df_b`.

The result is:

```
    colA  V1
 1:    9  NA
 2:    3  NA
 3:    9  NA
 4:    9  NA
 5:    3  NA
 6:   10 I,P
 7:   10 I,P
 8:    7   E
 9:    4   C
10:    7   E
```